# Make html table row clickable to call a servlet?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I want to call sevlet when I click on table row. I tried several methods, but non of them got right.
here is my jsp table and what I tried :

```
        <th>DESCRIPTION</th>

        <th>PRICE</th>
        <th>IMAGE</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
    <c:forEach var="employee" items="${allads}">

        <tr onclick="document.location ="datail_ad_viewer?page=${employee.brand}";">
            <td><a href="datail_ad_viewer?page=${1}"></a></td>
            <td>${employee.description}<br/>${employee.location}<br/>${employee.brand}          </td>

            <td>${employee.price}</td>
            <td width="150"><center><img height="80" width="120"     onerror="this.src='http://localhost:8080/images/default.png';" src=${employee.imageurl} />    </center></td>

        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the issue you are getting, any exception? Is your browser actually try loading datail_ad_viewer?

Comment: Nothing happens.
But if I used html page(index.html) instead of href="datail_ad_viewer?page=${1}" it redirect to that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to nest double quotes! Use `'` instead of `"` for either the inner or the outer string. Like this:

```
onclick="document.location='datail_ad_viewer?page=${employee.brand}';"
```

Comment: watz for -2 front of my question?

Comment: @user2833917: That means two people think your question is missing vital information, it's sloppy or otherwise bad.

Comment: @user2833917: One thing the tooltip text for the downvote button says is „not useful“. This is the reason I cast one of the two downvotes: I believe that your problem is *very* localized. Chances that someone who did the same mistake will Google or search SO and end up finding your question are negligible. This is not specific to click event handlers, nor to table rows, not even to jsp. This issue is a general coding issue for html, xml and related languages. But the question is phrased aiming at just this instance, so others in this situation won't find it. Therefore not useful to others.